# Changing of expression of halving amount every so often

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a questions that I need to succinctly answer to. I'll try and format the question in the realm of mathematics where people buy a hundred pies and eat a dozen pies of them. Also, I'm going to express the question in "High School" maths. Could the question be left in this format by mods and the answer also in a similar format so that, one, I can translate it to computer software, and two, understand it.

There is a factory that produces numbered blocks in numerical order starting from 1, each block contains 200 coins. Every 840,000 blocks they are supposed to halve the amount of coins in the block. This is expressed in the factory computer software as the following using a bitwise right shift assignment >>.

```
amount_of_coins = 200
amount_of_coins = amount_of_coins >> (block_number / 840000)
```

However, there is a change in the distribution of coins and the software needs to reflect the change. The number of coins is reduced at block number 204,640 to 80 coins a block but the reward needs to be halved at the same equivalent block number.

If there was 80 coins a block from the start the coin halving number would be every 2,100,000 blocks.

```
840,000 * (200/80) = 2,100,000
```

How can this change be expressed in the computer software?

I am not sure that it can be so neatly expressed anymore. I can work out the block number to halve the amount of coins for the first time with.

```
204,640 + ((840,000 - 204,640) * (200/80)) = 1793040
```

But to then halve every subsequent 2,100,000 blocks in a single expression does not seems tricky. I can break the solution into several lines but ideally a single expression using bitwise operator would be best and any C++ expressions or operators are allowed.

If I should go ask this in a coding forum then please tell me to go away and leave you kind folk alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$840,000\cdot\frac{200}{80} = 2,100,000$$

as your increment between halvings. This can be considered the slope of a line. You already gave the point where the first shift happens, so you have a point on the line of $(1, 1793040)$. This can be plugged into the equation of a line.
$$y = mx+b$$
$$1793040 = (2100000)(1)+b$$
$$b=-306960$$

But you don't want to solve for $y$, the block number, as that's what you have. You want to solve for $x$, the bit shift.

$$y = mx+b$$
$$y-b = mx$$
$$\frac{y-b}{m} = x$$

$$\frac{\text{(block number)+306960}}{2100000} = \text{bit shift}$$

$m$ is how often the halving happens, while $b$ is an offset because of the first halving. So then you have

```
amount_of_coins = amount_of_coins >> ((block_number + 306960)/2100000)
```